# Why aren't genetic triplets roughly evenly found in DNA?

Tags: dna

Sorry, the page I linked to is huge and you'll need to do a text search for "CG" to find the part I'm talking about.

I found a graph on this page (http://www.oftenpaper.net/sierpinski.htm) showing that the eight DNA sequences including CG, i.e. four *CG and four CG* sequences are much rarer than the others in a human X chromosome. I realise that this is only for one sample of a human X chromosome (not even all human chromosomes) but I was wondering why this is? Obviously, if *CG is rare CG* will be too.

From my limited understanding the equivalent RNA sequences would be *GC (redundant codes for four amino acids) and GC* (the only codes that produce Alanine). According to the [Wikipedia page on Alanine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alanine) it accounts for 7.8% of genetic amino acids, well over the average.

Is this representative across all DNA? Across all human DNA? What does DNA have against coding CG sequences, even if only in the X chromosome? Do other chromosomes have an abundance of CG sequences but are rare in others?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CpG_site

Comment: Or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CpG_site for desktop computers.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not specific to the X chromosome. It's a general trend. CG sequences are underrepresented in mammalian genomes. In fact, the very nucleotides C and G are underrepresented. Instead of the ~25% you'd expect by chance, the real numbers for the human genome are (calculated on the hg19 version of the UCSC human genome):

```
N: 234350281 = 7.5702%   <-- N means unknown
A: 844868045 = 27.2917%
C: 585017944 = 18.8978%
T: 846097277 = 27.3314%
G: 585360436 = 18.9089%
```

If we break this down by chromosome (chrM is the mitochondrial genome which should probably be ignored here), we get:

```
chrM    A:5113 (30.9%)  C:5192 (31.3%)  T:4086 (24.7%)  G:2180 (13.2%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr1    A:65570891 (29.1%)  C:47024412 (20.9%)  T:65668756 (29.1%)  G:47016562 (20.9%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr2    A:71102632 (29.2%)  C:47915465 (19.7%)  T:71239379 (29.3%)  G:47947042 (19.7%)  N:4994855 (2.1%)    
chr3    A:58713343 (29.6%)  C:38653197 (19.5%)  T:58760485 (29.7%)  G:38670110 (19.5%)  N:3225295 (1.6%)    
chr4    A:57932980 (30.9%)  C:35885806 (19.1%)  T:57952068 (30.9%)  G:35890822 (19.1%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr5    A:53672554 (30.2%)  C:35089383 (19.7%)  T:53804137 (30.3%)  G:35129186 (19.8%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr6    A:50554433 (29.5%)  C:33143287 (19.4%)  T:50533923 (29.5%)  G:33163423 (19.4%)  N:3720001 (2.2%)    
chr7    A:45997757 (29.6%)  C:31671670 (20.4%)  T:46047257 (29.6%)  G:31636979 (20.4%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr8    A:42767293 (29.9%)  C:28703983 (20.1%)  T:42715025 (29.9%)  G:28702621 (20.1%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr9    A:35260078 (29.3%)  C:24826212 (20.7%)  T:35243882 (29.3%)  G:24813259 (20.7%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr10   A:38330752 (28.3%)  C:27308648 (20.1%)  T:38376915 (28.3%)  G:27298423 (20.1%)  N:4220009 (3.1%)    
chr11   A:38307244 (29.2%)  C:27236798 (20.8%)  T:38317436 (29.2%)  G:27268038 (20.8%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr12   A:38604831 (28.8%)  C:26634995 (19.9%)  T:38624517 (28.9%)  G:26617050 (19.9%)  N:3370502 (2.5%)    
chr13   A:29336945 (30.7%)  C:18412698 (19.3%)  T:29425459 (30.8%)  G:18414776 (19.3%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr14   A:25992966 (29.4%)  C:18027132 (20.4%)  T:26197495 (29.7%)  G:18071947 (20.5%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr15   A:23620876 (23%)    C:17247582 (16.8%)  T:23597921 (23%)    G:17228387 (16.8%)  N:20836626 (20.3%)  
chr16   A:21724083 (27.5%)  C:17630040 (22.3%)  T:21828642 (27.7%)  G:17701988 (22.4%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr17   A:21159933 (27.2%)  C:17727956 (22.8%)  T:21206981 (27.3%)  G:17700340 (22.8%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr18   A:22465380 (28.8%)  C:14838685 (19%)    T:22489493 (28.8%)  G:14863671 (19%)    N:3420019 (4.4%)    
chr19   A:14390632 (25.8%)  C:13478255 (24.2%)  T:14428951 (25.9%)  G:13511145 (24.2%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr20   A:16523053 (27.8%)  C:13107828 (22%)    T:16725227 (28.1%)  G:13149412 (22.1%)  N:0 (0%)    
chr21   A:10422924 (21.7%)  C:7160212 (14.9%)   T:10348785 (21.5%)  G:7174721 (14.9%)   N:13023253 (27.1%)  
chr22   A:9094775 (17.7%)   C:8375984 (16.3%)   T:9054551 (17.6%)   G:8369235 (16.3%)   N:16410021 (32%)    
chrX    A:45648952 (30.2%)  C:29813353 (19.7%)  T:45772424 (30.3%)  G:29865831 (19.8%)  N:0 (0%)    
chrY    A:7667625 (29.9%)   C:5099171 (19.9%)   T:7733482 (30.1%)   G:5153288 (20.1%)   N:0 (0%)
```

As you can see, C and G are consistently less frequent than A and T across all chromosomes. The exception is the mitochondrial genome but that [is not the genome of a vertebrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbiogenesis). So, overall, A and T occur almost 10% more often than C and G. But why does this happen?

As far as I know, the reasons are not entirely clear. Some factors that affect this, however, are:

- The C of the CG dinucleotides can be [methytlated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_methylation). Methylation is a chemical modification of the nucleotide and plays an important role in the regulation of gene expression. The regulatory sequences that control the way that genes are expressed ([promoters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promoter_%28genetics%29)), are often rich in CG sequences (these localized overrepresentations of CG are called [CpG islands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CpG_site#CpG_islands)) which enable the control of the associated gene's expression by the mechanism of methylation (which can "turn off" a gene). Not the kind of thing you want to have occurring randomly in your genes.
- Methylated Cytosine (C) is often converted to Thymine (T):

  [image: Cytosine becomes Thymine]

  This would result in a gradual loss of C in favor of T. This theory had long been considered to be the main reason why CpG is so rare in mammalian genomes, but see the next point.
- I found a study from 2004 [[1]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378111904000836) that shows that, among other things, there is no correlation between CpG and TpA shortages, suggesting that the deamination of Cytosine to Thymine is not enough to explain the phenomenon.

I should also point out that the fact that Alanine represents  7.8% of all aminoacids in proteins does not say anything at all about the frequency with which its codons appear in the genome at large. Only ~2% of the human genome (genes are ~5% and exons, those parts of genes that are translated into proteins, only ~2%) actually codes for proteins so it is only in that 2% where you will see this overrepresentation (if one exists) of Alanine.

In conclusion, yes, the CpG shortage is a general feature of the human genome and not of chromosome X, but the precise reasons for this are not yet entirely clear (as far as I know, anyway).

#### References

1. [Jabbari K., and Bernardi G., *Gene* **333**:143-149, 2004](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378111904000836)